# Auto-resized guest display not working with ubuntu18.04 guest in virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution, ubuntu-18.04, lxde

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 Server with lxde and openbox as guest system in an virtual box 6.1 machine. (windows host)

The guest system starts lxde with an resolution of 1024x786 pixel.
If I resize the window/screen of the virtual box guest VM window, the resolution of the guest vm does not change to the new size of the virtual monitor.

That's unusual.
Usually, the guest system automatically changes the resolution, when the window of the virtual machine is enlarged.

I have installed the virtual box 6.1.0 guest additions. I also tried the `lxrandr` tool in the ubuntu guest and set resolution to "automatic", but the  settings was restored to 1024x768 after reopening the `lxrandr` tool.

If I change the resolution insight the guest OS using `lxrandr` to 1920x1080, the new resolution is applied, and the guest window is auto-resized. But if I change the guest window size (using the mouse), the guest resolution sets back to 1024x768.

By the way: I'm using the VMSVGA Virtual Box graphic adapter (but I have the same problem with all other adapters) and the "Auto-resized guest display" is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. However, I noticed that the guest is still able to to auto-resize if it runs LinuxAdditions from VirtualBox 6.0.12 instead of those from the corresponding host 6.1.0. Resize is a bit slow, though.